# Azure notification Hub stop sending toast message

Tags: azure, notifications, azure-notificationhub

From 17 Jul azure stop sending toast Notification message (only toast, all other type working well).

In the azure console, test message

[image]

i can see "The Notification payload is invalid", how can fix this issue?

Same issue using c# code from UWP App or other type, before 17 Jul all working ok

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delayed response; I acknowledge that my reply was overdue. There was a bug identified by our engineering team and the fix was rolled out.  Retrying the operation, doesn't show this error anymore. We'd a discussion and update on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1336114/since-07-17-2023-i-have-a-lot-of-payload-errors-wh).